# How to change column names in data frame in R?

Tags: r

```
 names(mydat)[c(name)]<-c("newname")
```

From this, I know that the column/variable name "name" of the data frame mydat is replaced with "newname".

My question is if, I want to do this by a loop so that I will have some thing like:

newname1 newname2 newname3 newname4 and so on, how do I do it?

This is what did and it did not work:

```
for(i in 1:4){
names(mydat)[c(name)]<-c("newname"i)
}
```

Is there a way to code this?
many thanks to all who could be of help.
Owusu Isaac

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely about programming.

Comment: If you need to rename some ugly variable names (e.g., abcde_1_1, abcde_2_2, abcde_3_3 ... ) as it frequently happens in some datasets downloaded from Qualtrics:

    `ugly_vars <- names(dplyr::select(df, starts_with("abcde_")))`


    `names(ESM_df[ugly_vars]) <- str_c("abc_", 1:length(ugly_vars))`

Answer (score 10):

Most obvious solution would be to change your code in for loop with the following:

```
   names(mydat)[c(name)] <- paste("newname",i,sep="")
```

But you need to clarify what your variable `name` is. At the moment this loop will do 4 renames of the single column.

In general if the names which you want to change are in vector, this is a standard subsetting procedure:

```
 names(mydat)[names(mydat)%in% names_to_be_changed] <- name_changes
```

Comment: Hello Mpiktas, your solution works excellently. many thanks. and thanks to all as well

Comment: @Owusu, the expression of gratitude in this site is upvoting of the answers and their acceptance. See the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). Either way, glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `sprintf` or `paste`, like this:

```
names(mydat)<-sprintf("name%d",1:10)
```

Also, note that the `names(mydat)[c(name)]` is a more-less a nonsense; `c(name)` is equivalent to writing just `name` and means "get the value of variable called `name`'; bracket will at least extract elements of `names(mydat)` but only if `name` variable holds a numeric or boolean index.

If you want to replace columns called `name` with `name1, name2, ..., nameN`, use something like this:

```
names(mydat)[names(mydat)=="name"]<-sprintf("name%d",1:sum(names(mydat)=="name"))
```

EDIT: Well, if you just want to remove duplicated column names, there is even easier way; R has a `make.names` function which fixes this problem; it can be used like this:

```
names(mydat)<-make.names(names(mydat),unique=TRUE)
```

Even shorter, the same can be obtained only by writing:

```
data.frame(mydat)->mydat #The magic is in check.names, but it is TRUE by default
```

Comment: @mbq, == does partial matching for strings?

Comment: @mpiktas No, but only exact matching is needed here. `grepl` would be OK to do the more general job.

Comment: @mbq, yes but that assumes that there are multiple columns with the same name. R allows that, but I try to avoid using this feature.

Comment: @mpiktas Apparently so does the OP, thus this question.

Comment: @mbq thanks for clarifying the confusion with _names(mydat)[c(name)]_ Since the OP has written _I know that the column/variable name "name"_ I was like "wow that is possible ?" and tried to access the names by name ... stupid me ;). May I humbly suggest to edit the question ?

Comment: @steffen I'm afraid it would be confusing; but a comment under question is ok. We still don't really know the whole context of OP's problem... :-( It seems the `name` variable is set previously.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I solved it with this code:

```
names(mydat) <- paste("newname", 1:ncol(mydat), sep="");
```